# Embedded YouTube with iframe in mobile safari not showing fullscreen button on small width

Tags: reactjs, iframe, youtube, mobile-safari

I have a website where I can embed youtube videos. Everything works great, except on mobile safari, where the fullscreen toggle on the right side of the controls is not showing when the width of the iframe is too small. My question is if there is a way to always force show the fullscreen button?

Here the player width is `345px`:

[image]

Here the player width is `346px`:

[image]

However I have places where the width of the player is for example `312px` and I would want the fullscreen button to be always visible.

This is how my iframe code looks:

```
    <iframe
      ref={$player}
      src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}?playsinline=1`}
      frameBorder={0}
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      allowFullScreen
    />
```